# Car vibrates and has mild drone at 15-45 mph

Tags: tires, wheels, alignment, struts

I bought a used car with worn-out tires. Between speeds of 14-45mph the car vibrates and produces low frequency growling/droning noise. When above 45 mph, vibrations go away but drone pitch increases (volume remains same) though its not too bad.

Few details:
Car : RWD BMW z4
- No vibrations in steering, just vibrations in seat.

- Alignment was done before purchase by the seller. (I've the receipt)
- Rear RFT tires are totally gone ~5% tread life left. Front non-RFT have 70% tread. I'm getting them replaced soon.
- No difference between accelerating, braking,cruising, or coasting. sound and vibration remain constant in the speed range.
- I scanned obd port, no error/fault codes.
- brakes squeal when brake paddle is pressed lightly. Higher pressure and its gone.

Is it worn out rear tires or something more serious?

Comment: I am betting it is the tires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the tires changed, and issues is gone. So for anyone else facing this issue, if its speed dependent and no noise difference between braking,cornering, accelerating, its the tires.